# Is my jQuery .load bloacked by the CMS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, movabletype

I am using prettyPhoto inside a Movable Type CMS page. To make it work I have to use a

```
<p>
    <mt:setvarblock name="html_head" append="1">
        JS scripts here
    </mt:include>
</p>
```

section. To make a gallery with 30-40 pictures, I have to add a block for each picture that looks something like this:

```
<a href="pathtoimage.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[GalleryName]" title="Some title">
    <img src="pathtothumbnail.jpg" alt="alt text" height="120" width="120" />
</a>
```

I want to generate these entries from a csv file using a (python) script and put into a separate file on the web server. Then I use this code to load these entries into the page:

```
<div id="divTestArea1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#divTestArea1").load("output_en.txt");
    });
</script>
```

When I load the page the thumbnails show up, but when I click them the pathtoimage.jpg is loaded instead of prettyphoto.

My question: Am I doing something wrong or is movable type blocking the execution for security reasons? How to debug this? I have firebug but no idea what to look for.

P.S: When pasting the entries directly into the page it works as expected.

Edit: full working code

```
<p>
    <mt:setvarblock name="html_head" append="1">
        <script src="../gallery/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../gallery/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="../gallery/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </mt:setvarblock> 
    <mt:include name="include/header.tmpl"> 
        <div id="divTestArea1"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                <!--$("#divTestArea1").load("../gallery/output_en.txt");-->
                $("#divTestArea1").load("../gallery/output_en.txt", function() {
                    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
                });
            });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">// <![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({social_tools: false});
            });
        // ]]></script>
    </mt:include>
</p>
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: I was only getting a 404 on `query.textresizer.js` because its not on the webserver, and a `TypeError: jQuery(...).textresizer is not a function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the prettyPhoto() call after the AJAX has finished loading, because at the moment the plugin is being executed on page load, *before* the element it is targeting is available in the DOM.

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     $("#divTestArea1").load("../gallery/output_en.txt", function() {
         $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
     });
   });
</script>
```